# When do I need to remove an observer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which has an `AVPlayer` in it. I'be added an observer to the `playerItem` to know when the video has reached its end. The cell can get a new file to play, in which case it replaces the `player` and the `playerItem` with new instances. In previous times when I've added  an observer I had to remove the it in dealloc or the app would crash.

This time, I've noticed that even if I don't remove the observer before removing the `playerItem` everything works fine.

Why don't I need to remove the observer in this case?

```
@interface CallResultTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

-(void) embedUrl:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

```
-(void) embedUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    if (self.url == nil || ![self.url isEqual:url]) {
        if (self.player != nil) {
            [self.player pause];
            self.player = nil;
            //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
            //                                                name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
            //                                              object:self.playerItem];
            self.playerItem = nil;
            //...
        }
        if (url != nil) {
            self.playerItem = [myUrls playerItemWithURL:url];
            self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
            self.url = url;
            //...
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:)
                                                         name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                       object:self.playerItem];
        }
    }
    [self.player play];
}

-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [self.playerItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self.player play];
}
```

I also call `remove observer` in `dealloc`:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                  object:self.playerItem];
}
```

<sup>ARC is turned on.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Apple Developer Release [Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/#10_11NotificationCenter):

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated.

Which means you don't need to remove observer from iOS 9 or OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove in dealloc.

```
 - (void)dealloc {
   [super dealloc];
    //add remove observer code
 }
```

Comment: I have it in dealloc also, see edit, but why don't I need to remove it each time that I destroy the object that I'm observing?

Comment: before ios 9 means in ios8 it was crashing because it tries to send message also after deallocation but in ios9 if resource not found it removesObserver automatically.

Comment: So do I need to put the remove inside embedUrl or not?

Comment: which os version do you target ?

Comment: We are interested mainly in iOS 9 and up.

Comment: then you should not add remove observer code because ios9 handels it with it self by checking the existence of object if registered object not found it automatically remove the observer.\

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure, view controller is going to pop, then remove observer.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if self.isMovingFromParentViewController()
    {
        //View controller was popped
        //Remove any observer.
    }
}
```